# 16GB 1600mhz vs 16GB 1866mhz RAM for Macbook Pro 13" mid 2012

Tags: memory

Want To Ask
i did geekbench test on 2 types of RAMs on my  MBP 13" 2.9ghz i7 mid 2012.

1-Crucial 16GB Kit (8GBx2) DDR3L-1600 SODIMM 
32bit test
2913
Single-Core Score
6105
Multi-Core Score

64 bit test
3132
Single-Core Score
6754
Multi-Core Score.

2-Kingston HyperX Impact Black 16GB(8GBx2) 1866MHz DDR3L Laptop RAM (Low Voltage - HX318LS11IB/8)
32bit test
2715
Single-Core Score
5814
Multi-Core Score.

64bit test
2986
Single-Core Score
6975
Multi-Core Score

so i would like to know any opinion about RAM is better for my Macbook Pro 13" 2.9ghz i7 mid 2012??[image]

Answer (score 1):

2012 MacBook Pro 13" specification states that it [supports 1600 MHz RAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201165#1). So, Kingston modules do not have an advantage, as the memory will run at 1600 MHz.

Purely, from numbers point of view, your geekbench results point to Crucial being faster. However, I suspect it is due to variance. You can try to rerun the same test several times and see how the scores differ from run to run.

Both Kingston and Crucial are well known brands with low failure rates. And unless you are going to put your computer under heavy load, memory intensive constant tasks, you will not notice any difference between the two in terms of speed. So, if I were you, I would buy whichever is cheaper.